# Having trouble with rake assets:precompile - wrong version of ruby on Windows box

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm absolutely flummoxed!
I'm trying to use rake to precompile my assets on a windows development box.  I've done it before, but now it seems to be broken.

rake assets:precompile

and

bundle exec assets:precompile

both yield the message "Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5"

ruby -v shows 'ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [i386-mingw32]

which ruby shows '/c/Ruby22/bin/ruby'

Even adding 
  ruby '2.2.3'
to the second line of my Gem file doesn't change anything.

Any ideas what I'm missing?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I feel REALLY stupid!

I was editing the wrong Gemfile.